# Interaction between 2 classes maybe

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a mini game with 2 classes: the menu and the play. I am trying to randomly change the image of an object in the play class by clicking a button in the menu class.

So, in the menu class I add a button and add input listener so that when I click

```
playbutton.addListener(new InputListener() {
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
game.setScreen(new lessonclass (game));
lessonclass.currentlevel = MathUtils.random(2);
return true;
        }
        });
```

in the play class, I add static int level, an object

```
public grid ( Vector2 position, Vector2 size) {
    texture0 = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("zero.jpg"));
    texture1 = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("one.jpg"));
    texture2 = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("two.jpg"));
    texture3 = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("three.jpg"));
    this.position = position;
    this.size     = size;

}

public void update(){

}

public void draw0(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture0, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);   
}

public void draw1(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture1, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);   
}

public void draw2(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture2, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);   
}

if (TouchDown) {System.out.println ("" + level);}
```

When I run the program, the level value VARIES between 0 and 1 but the object always draw image batch.
If I change the code in the menu class so that it only brings me to play class and the in play class I change the level to

```
public static int level = MathUtils.random(1);
```

then my level value varies and the object randomly draws either batch image or batch1 image.
However, I want to do this from the menu class. Since the program runs and I cant think of the logic error, I am stuck now. Why can't I change my object image by clicking the button in the menu class?

Comment: This much code is not enough to solve your problem. What values you are assigning to batch and batch1?

Comment: this is my batch batch.draw(texture0, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y) and this is my batch 1 batch1.draw(texture1, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);

Comment: @pisces15 Edit your question to include the new code.  It's a lot more readable there than it is in a comment :)

Comment: ooh, i see. okay. thanks Naman, thaks Brian

Comment: you can inspect value of `level` variable and find out is the value getting changed or not from menu class.

Comment: it changes. but somehow the object cant detect it. if i give level variable a value directly, it is fine. but if i refer the level variable to any int outside its class. the object detect the level as null even if it has value when i check it